# probability question : what are the chances that at least 1 out of 150 passengers are infected

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There are $10{,}000$ corona patients in a city of $7{,}500{,}000$ people.
> $150$ people fly on a plane, what are the chances that at least $1$ person is infected?

I solved it using the below approach
select 1 infected patient / select 150 out of total population.

$$\dfrac{{10000 \choose 1}}{{7500000 \choose 150}}$$ which is approximately equals 0,

My friend suggested a different solution and came to a value of 19.3% probability

His approach:
pct of patient infected is $10000/7500000 = 0.0013$

and pct of 1 person infected = 1 - no person infected
= $1-( (1 - 0.0013)^{150} )=0.19$

What is the correct answer? and why is any of the approach incorrect?

Comment: I assume you mean "$150$ people fly on a _plane_".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither.

The probability of at least one person is infected is one minus the probability that all are healthy, which is

$$1-\tfrac{{7500000-10000 \choose 150}}{{7500000 \choose 150}}=0.18$$

Your friend assumes people are sick independently. This would have been true if the wording was "each person is sick with probability 0.0013" or something similar. As you phrased it, there are exactly 10,000 people who are sick in the city. Since the sample (150) is small relative to the population, there is no much difference.

Your approach is wrong as you only consider 1 sick person and not at least one. Moreover, you don't account for the number of options to choose the other 149 passengers out of the healthy population.

Finally, please use MathJax to typset your question.

Comment: thank you. this is clear to me now. apologies for not using correct formating, still new to this site.